# C++: More and more complex bugs misleading the debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

It seems like the bugs in my project are evolving. While in the beginning time, causers of program crashes were easily to spot using the debugger (the line it points to after the program crashes), it's different now.

Many bugs cause the program to crash in completely arbitary places not even closely related to them.

- How can I spot bugs "hiding" from the debugger in a better way?

(I use Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile your code for memory corruption, [memory overwrites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52bz2688.aspx) and [memory leaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Root cause analysis.

When you find an obvious bug, don't just fix the bug, fix the coding style that allowed it.

Comment: The *coding style* apparently was leaving the Lua stack messy by one item after a C function.

Comment: +1, I really like this advice.

Comment: @Komn: In that case, you could have caught it with an RAII object that saves the Lua stack depth on entry, and verifies it on return.  In a release build you can skip the checks.  Then, by adopting a coding style which uses this RAII stack checker instead of calling Lua stack manipulation functions directly, you'd have found the problem very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use memory corruption checking utilities, like gflags or debug heap. "Floating" crushes almost always come from corrupted memory in C++ programs

Answer (score 1):

If you have any code using raw memory and pointers, replace it by memory allocated using std::vector and its iterators. It will compile to exactly the same speedy code in Release mode, but in Debug mode it will used checked iterators, which will catch some bugs as early as possible.